Docker Environment Setup for Cloudera and Spark Jobs
I am beginning to study Docker and I have a challenge to build an environment with the following requirements:

Cloudera Docker Container: This container will run continuously, 24 hours a day.

Spark Jobs Docker Container: This container will run different Spark jobs, with each job running at least once a day.


Requirements:

Data Storage: The Spark Jobs Docker container needs to write CSV files to the HDFS located within the Cloudera Docker container.

Log Management: The Spark Jobs Docker container must also save the application logs in a specific directory inside the Cloudera Docker container.



How would the Docker Compose and project structure look based on this setup?
Do you have an example?
repo-project-job-spark-2
    |
    | docker-compose.yml
    | docker/conf
    | logs
    | src
      |
      | - application.py


You don't need yarn or hdfs. You can use Spark history server and Minio (or hadoop Ozone). The Cloudera quickstart container isn't maintained anymore and is very outdated.

in this case, I wanted the cloudera container to keep a place to store, for example, hive and hdfs. What do you recommend in this case? and in advance, thank you for your support! @OneCricketeer

MinIO or Ozone are fine replacements for hdfs. Hive metastore + Postgres can be ran as a separate container for using with SparkSQL, but Hive isn't necessary for just managing CSV files

I've never heard of Apache Ozone. From what I understand, I could replace the cloudera container with ozone, right? @OneCricketeer

For storage, yes. It doesn't replace yarn (or a Spark master and history server). This page covers how to use Spark with it (on Kubernetes) https://ozone.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/recipe/sparkozonefsk8s.html
